# show the menu bar

Tags: ubuntu, menu

Unintentionally while I was doing the upgrade ubuntu to the 16:04 version, hung up the computer and gave an error in the installation, I managed after many conflicts when installing managed.

My standard desktop that use is gnome-classic but for some reason the menu bar does not appear, tried reinstalling the packages and a lot of little things, like do not do idea what to do, I'm using the community.

The <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>f2</kbd> command is not working.

If anyone has any idea what to do please help me I.

**UPDATE**

I also tried this command to restore the compiz settings but also did not show the bar.

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity
unity --reset-icons
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem for reparecer the top menu installing gnome-classic.

To install Gnome Classic in Ubuntu and derivatives, do the following:

Step 1. Open a terminal (Using the CTRL + ALT + T);
Step 2. Update the APT with the command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Step 3. Now install the program with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
```

Step 4. In newer systems, install the program with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-flashback
```

Step 5. Once installed, shut down the current session;
Step 6. When you are on the login screen, click on the logo and the menu icon that appears, select the Gnome Flashback (Compiz) option.